# Java vs. Julia: Differences in JIT Compiling and Resulting Performance

Tags: performance, compilation, julia, jit, multiple-dispatch

I've recently started reading about JIT compilation. On another note, I've read that well-written Julia code often performs on-par with statically compiled languages (see, e.g., [paragraph 2 of the introduction section of the Julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/)) while I've recurrently heard [Java often does not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#Performance). Why is that?

On the surface, they seem to have in common that they both run JIT-compiled bytecode in a VM (although I am aware that Java dynamically infers which code to JIT). While I can rationalize the performance difference in Julia vs. (purely) interpreted languages like (vanilla) Python, how come two JIT-compiled languages have such different reputations for performance? Speaking of performance, I am particularly referring to scientific computing applications.

Please note that this question is intentionally phrased broadly. I feel like its possible answers could give me insights into what defines fast Julia code, given the way Julia's compiler works in comparison to other JIT compiled languages.

Comment: Please include links for your sources; e.g. *"Also, I've heard that Julia often performs on-par with statically compiled languages while Java typically does not."*   It is hard to give an objective answer to a question that based on unattributed or unsubstantiated rumors.

Comment: *"How does the multiple-dispatch paradigm of Julia affect the way it is JIT-compiled as compared to Java, and does this also explain the difference in performance?"* - 1) If anything it would make Julia performance worse.  2) So, no, it doesn't explain the difference.

Comment: *"I'd definitely appreciate a better understanding of how both languages work under the hood but would also be thankful if you could briefly explain compiling-related jargon (I currently do not have formal CS background)."* - Sorry, but that is way Too Broad for a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Also ... note that when you compare performance of language implementations, you need to ask ... performance doing what?  Java and Julia are targeted at different application domains.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have now added sources. Please note that this is my first StackOverflow question, apologies if it does not meet the content guidelines. I will consider phrasing my question differently.

Comment: I have now tried to address some of your previous concerns. I acknowledge that this is a rather broad question, aimed at general understanding of JIT compiled languages rather than any specific problem. If you can refer me to a board which is better suited to my question, I am happy to take your advice.

Answer (score 4):

While AFAIK there is currently one implementation of Julia, there are **several implementations** of Java and not all behave the same nor use the same technics internally. Thus **it does not mean much to compare languages**. For example, GCJ is a GNU compiler meant to compile Java codes to native ones (ie. no JIT nor bytecode). It is now a defunct project since the open-source JIT-based implementations super-seeded this project (AFAIK even performance-wise).

The primary reference Java VM implementation is *HotSpot* (made by Oracle). The JIT of HotSpot use an adaptative strategy for compiling functions so to reduce the **latency** of the compilation. The code can be interpreted for a short period of time and if it is executed many times, then the JIT use more aggressive optimizations with multiple levels. As a result hot loops are very aggressively optimized while glue code executed once is mostly interpreted. Meanwhile, Julia is based on the *LLVM* compiler stack capable of producing very efficient code (it is used by Clang which is a compiler used to compile C/C++ code to native one), but it is also not yet very well suited for very dynamic codes (it works but the latency is pretty big compared to other existing JIT implementations).

The thing is **Java and Julia target different domains**. Java is used for example on embedded systems where latency matters a lot. It is also use for GUI applications and Web servers. Introducing a high latency during the execution is not very reasonable. This is especially why Java implementation spent a lot of time in the past so to optimize the GC (Garbage Collector) in order to reduce the latency of collections. Julia mainly target HPC/scientific applications that do not care much about latency. The main goal of Julia is to minimize the *wall-clock time* and not the responsiveness of the application.

> I've read that well-written Julia code often performs on-par with statically compiled languages

Well, optimizing JITs like the one of Julia or the one of HotSpot are very good nowadays to compile *scalar codes* in *hot loops*. Their weakness lies in the capability to apply **high-level expensive computations**. For example, optimizing compilers like ICC/PGI can use the [polyhedral model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope_model) so to completely rewrite loops and vectorize them efficiently using *SIMD instructions*. This is frequent in HPC (numerically intensive) applications but very rare in embedded/Web/GUI ones. The use of the best specific instructions on the available platform is not always great in most JIT implementations (eg. bit operations) though the situation is rapidly improving. On the other hand, JIT can outperform static compilers by using runtime informations. For example, they can assume a value is a constant and optimize expressions based on that (eg. a runtime-dependent stride of 1 of a multi-dimensional array do not need additional multiplications). Still, static compilers can do similar optimisation with profile-guided optimizations (unfortunately rarely used in practice).

However, there is a catch: languages likes C/C++ compiled natively have access to lower-level features barely available in Java. This is a bit different in Julia since the link with native language code is easier and inline assembly is possible (as pointed out by @OscarSmith) enabling skilled developers to write efficient wrappers. Julia and Java use a GC that can speed up a bit some unoptimized codes but also slow down a lot some others (typically code manipulating big data-structures with a lot of references likes trees and graphs, especially in parallel codes). This is why a C/C++ code can significantly outperform a Julia/Java code. While JIT implementations can sometime (but rarely) outperform static C/C++ compilers, **no compilers are perfect** and there are case where nearly all implementations perform poorly. The use of (low-level) **intrinsics** enable developers to implement possibly faster codes at the expense of a lower portability and a higher complexity. This is not rare for SIMD code since auto-vectorization is far from being great so far. More generally, the access to lower-level features (eg. operating system specific functions, parallel tools) help to write faster codes for *skilled programmers*.

Chosen algorithms and methods matters often far more than the target language implementation. The best algorithm/method in one language implementation may not be the best in another. Two best algorithms/methods of two different implementation are generally hard to compare (it is fair to compare only the performance of codes if one is is nearly impossible to maintain and is very hard/long to write without bugs?). This is partially why **comparing language implementation is so difficult**, even on a specific problem to solve.

> (purely) interpreted languages like (vanilla) Python

While the standard implementation of Python is the CPython interpreter, there are fast JIT for Python like PyPy or Pyston.

> Speaking of performance, I am particularly referring to scientific computing applications

Note that scientific computing applications is still quite broad. While physicist tends to write heavily numerically intensive applications operating on large contiguous arrays where the use of multiple threads and SIMD instruction is critical, biologist tends to write codes requiring very different optimizations. For example, genomic codes tends to do a lot of string matching operations. They also often make use of complex data-structures/algorithms (eg. phylogenetic tree, compression).
Some Java features like boxing are performance killers for such applications though there are often complex way to mitigate their cost.

---

You may be interested by this famous language benchmark:

- [Julia VS C-GCC](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/julia-gcc.html) (one can see that Julia and Java are slow for binary trees, as expected, certainly due to the GC, though the Java's GC is more efficient at the expense of a bigger memory usage)
- [Julia VS Java-OpenJDK](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/julia.html)
- [C-GCC VS C-Clang](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/c.html)

As you can see in the benchmark, the fastest implementations are generally the more-complex and/or bigger ones using the best algorithms and lower-level methods/tricks.

Comment: "have access to lower-level features barely available in Julia/Java." this is false. Julia lets you include native code or llvm bytecode directly. Writing assembly in julia is as easy (or maybe easier) than it is in C++

Comment: Well, you can use JNI also in Java but this is not a Java code anymore. The same thing for Julia or even Python though Julia can call native functions with a reduced cost compared to the two others. However, I did not know inline assembly was possible. I corrected this part (and added more infos about the GC). Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for updating it! One other comment is that the binary tree benchmark rules explicitly prevent languages with a GC from using different allocation strategies (ie arena allocation), so it's only kind of a fair benchmark. That said, Julia's GC is far from optimal and receiving a lot of work at the moment. I am fairly optimistic that Julia 1.9 will have some significant improvements in GC speed.